# TPU inceptionV3 tensor had NaN values

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tpu

I am trying to use inceptionV3 and TPU to generate embeddings of pictures. As a base code, I am using the experimental model for inceptionV3 but I changed the loss and how batches are generated. 
And i am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Model/inception_v3.py", line 879, in <module>
    app.run(main) # starts Abseil app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "Model/inception_v3.py", line 858, in main
    input_fn=imagenet_train.input_fn, steps=FLAGS.train_steps_per_eval)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2457, in train
    rendezvous.raise_errors()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/error_handling.py", line 128, in raise_errors
    six.reraise(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2452, in train
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 358, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1124, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1158, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1407, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 676, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1171, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1270, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1255, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1327, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1091, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1152, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1328, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1348, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Gradient for InceptionV3/Mixed_5b/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/beta:0 is NaN : Tensor had NaN values
         [[node CheckNumerics_23 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py:1112) ]]
```

The loss i am using is triplet loss from tensorflow.

EDIT: When I use flag `--use-tpu=False` then it works but I don't see any load on the host machine but I see some usage on the TPU.

Comment: Did you fix this, and if so, what was the specific solution?

Comment: @Kevin if I remember correctly it was related to the images sizes. I had to upscale the images to match the image size that was used for the pre-trained model.